# qfx5300 fan issue

Tags: juniper

I have a 2x QFX3500 in virtual chassis mode and every 1-2 month one of my Fan trays showed as failed and everything is ok , Fan trays are spining at the normal speed they have 1unit free space from up and bottom of every switch, and here is the switch output :

```
Class Item Status Measurement
Power FPC 0 Power Supply 0 OK
FPC 0 Power Supply 1 OK
FPC 1 Power Supply 0 OK
FPC 1 Power Supply 1 OK
Temp FPC 0 Sensor TopLeft I OK 21 degrees C / 69 degrees F
FPC 0 Sensor TopRight I OK 22 degrees C / 71 degrees F
FPC 0 Sensor TopLeft E OK 35 degrees C / 95 degrees F
FPC 0 Sensor TopRight E OK 33 degrees C / 91 degrees F
FPC 0 Sensor TopMiddle I OK 31 degrees C / 87 degrees F
FPC 0 Sensor TopMiddle E OK 31 degrees C / 87 degrees F
FPC 0 Sensor Bottom I OK 37 degrees C / 98 degrees F
FPC 0 Sensor Bottom E OK 30 degrees C / 86 degrees F
FPC 0 Sensor Die Temp OK 42 degrees C / 107 degrees F
FPC 0 Sensor Mgmnt Brd I OK 21 degrees C / 69 degrees F
FPC 0 Sensor Switch I OK 31 degrees C / 87 degrees F
FPC 1 Sensor TopLeft I OK 21 degrees C / 69 degrees F
FPC 1 Sensor TopRight I OK 20 degrees C / 68 degrees F
FPC 1 Sensor TopLeft E OK 27 degrees C / 80 degrees F
FPC 1 Sensor TopRight E OK 27 degrees C / 80 degrees F
FPC 1 Sensor TopMiddle I OK 27 degrees C / 80 degrees F
FPC 1 Sensor TopMiddle E OK 34 degrees C / 93 degrees F
FPC 1 Sensor Bottom I OK 33 degrees C / 91 degrees F
FPC 1 Sensor Bottom E OK 33 degrees C / 91 degrees F
FPC 1 Sensor Die Temp OK 41 degrees C / 105 degrees F
FPC 1 Sensor Mgmnt Brd I OK 19 degrees C / 66 degrees F
FPC 1 Sensor Switch I OK 27 degrees C / 80 degrees F
Fans FPC 0 Fan Tray 0 OK Spinning at normal speed
FPC 0 Fan Tray 1 OK Spinning at normal speed
FPC 0 Fan Tray 2 Failed
FPC 1 Fan Tray 0 OK Spinning at normal speed
FPC 1 Fan Tray 1 OK Spinning at normal speed
FPC 1 Fan Tray 2 OK Spinning at normal speed



show chassis alarms
1 alarms currently active
Alarm time Class Description
2020-11-06 04:44:17 UTC Major FPC 0 Fan 2 not spinning



Hardware inventory:
Item             Version  Part number  Serial number     Description
Chassis                                X5461             Virtual Chassis
Routing Engine 0          BUILTIN      BUILTIN           QFX Routing Engine
  da0    7632 MB  QYR8000F4                              Nand Flash
Routing Engine 1          BUILTIN      BUILTIN           QFX Routing Engine
  da0    7632 MB  QYR8000F4                              Nand Flash
FPC 0            REV 07   750-043171   X5461-C           QFX3500-48S4Q
  CPU                     BUILTIN      BUILTIN           FPC CPU
  PIC 0                   BUILTIN      BUILTIN           48x 10G-SFP+
    Xcvr 1       REV 01   740-021308   AUR1870           SFP+-10G-SR
    Xcvr 2       REV 01   740-021308   MTF075T           SFP+-10G-SR
    Xcvr 3       REV 01   740-021308   MTG02CZ           SFP+-10G-SR
    Xcvr 4       REV 01   740-021308   AUR158P           SFP+-10G-SR
    Xcvr 5       REV 01   740-021308   AUS0219           SFP+-10G-SR
    Xcvr 6       REV 01   740-021308   AQL16DW           SFP+-10G-SR
    Xcvr 7       REV 01   740-021308   MTG0N8M           SFP+-10G-SR
    Xcvr 8       REV 01   740-021308   AUR1B2M           SFP+-10G-SR
    Xcvr 9       REV 01   740-021308   AUR172G           SFP+-10G-SR
    Xcvr 10      REV 01   740-021308   AUR17QE           SFP+-10G-SR
    Xcvr 36      REV 01   740-021308   AUR17MN           SFP+-10G-SR
    Xcvr 37      REV 01   740-021308   MTG05PW           SFP+-10G-SR
    Xcvr 38      REV 01   740-021308   MTG0PX2           SFP+-10G-SR
    Xcvr 39      REV 01   740-021308   MTG0L35           SFP+-10G-SR
    Xcvr 40      REV 01   740-021308   MTG0FKC           SFP+-10G-SR
    Xcvr 41      REV 01   740-021308   MTG0N8H           SFP+-10G-SR
    Xcvr 42      REV 01   740-021308   AUS021E           SFP+-10G-SR
    Xcvr 43      REV 01   740-021308   AUS02Q4           SFP+-10G-SR
    Xcvr 44      REV 01   740-021308   MTG026X           SFP+-10G-SR
    Xcvr 45      REV 01   740-021308   MTG0HML           SFP+-10G-SR
    Xcvr 46      REV 01   740-021308   MTG0E4P           SFP+-10G-SR
    Xcvr 47      REV 01   740-021308   MTG0PKP           SFP+-10G-SR
  PIC 1                   BUILTIN      BUILTIN           4x 40G-QSFP+
  MGMT BRD       REV 13   750-036946   ACMC64          QFX3500-MGMT-RJ45-AFI
  Power Supply 0 Rev 05   740-032091   WA12972           JPSU-650W-AC-AFI
  Power Supply 1 Rev 05   740-032091   VK10387           JPSU-650W-AC-AFI
  Fan Tray 0
  Fan Tray 1
  Fan Tray 2
FPC 1            REV 10   750-043171   DC607-C           QFX3500-48S4Q
  CPU                     BUILTIN      BUILTIN           FPC CPU
  PIC 0                   BUILTIN      BUILTIN           48x 10G-SFP+
    Xcvr 3       REV 01   740-021308   MTG09LA           SFP+-10G-SR
    Xcvr 4       REV 01   740-021308   MTG06AB           SFP+-10G-SR
    Xcvr 5       REV 01   740-021308   AUR17B2           SFP+-10G-SR
    Xcvr 6       REV 01   740-021308   MTG01TH           SFP+-10G-SR
    Xcvr 7       REV 01   740-021308   MUP1ZBL           SFP+-10G-SR
    Xcvr 8       REV 01   740-021308   AQ40T5R           SFP+-10G-SR
    Xcvr 9       REV 01   740-021308   MTG0CLV           SFP+-10G-SR
    Xcvr 10      REV 01   740-021308   MTG0PSL           SFP+-10G-SR
    Xcvr 11      REV 01   740-021308   AUR14BM           SFP+-10G-SR
    Xcvr 36      REV 01   740-021308   MTG0738           SFP+-10G-SR
    Xcvr 37      REV 01   740-021308   AUR17QJ           SFP+-10G-SR
    Xcvr 38      REV 01   740-021308   AUR17UQ           SFP+-10G-SR
    Xcvr 39      REV 01   740-021308   AUR17U6           SFP+-10G-SR
    Xcvr 40      REV 01   740-021308   AQD2TPF           SFP+-10G-SR
    Xcvr 41      REV 01   740-021308   AQ41HW5           SFP+-10G-SR
    Xcvr 42      REV 01   740-021308   MTG02A6           SFP+-10G-SR
    Xcvr 43      REV 01   740-021308   AUR18KM           SFP+-10G-SR
    Xcvr 44      REV 01   740-021308   AUR1425           SFP+-10G-SR
    Xcvr 45      REV 01   740-021308   MTG0N8J           SFP+-10G-SR
    Xcvr 46      REV 01   740-021308   MTG0EQX           SFP+-10G-SR
    Xcvr 47      REV 01   740-021308   MTG0LJQ           SFP+-10G-SR
  PIC 1                   BUILTIN      BUILTIN           4x 40G-QSFP+
  MGMT BRD       REV 13   750-036946   ACLN326         QFX3500-MGMT-RJ45-AFI
  Power Supply 0 REV 06   740-032091   1GA63120795       JPSU-650W-AC-AFI
  Power Supply 1 REV 06   740-032091   1GA63120801       JPSU-650W-AC-AFI
  Fan Tray 0
  Fan Tray 1
  Fan Tray 2
```

the strange part is Fan Tray 2 LED is ON and it's not off and when i put a little tissue paper on fan tray 2 it seems the fan tray is working but i do not know why does in qfx it shows as failed,

i have reboot whole of the switches but the issue still exists,

here is picture of the switch :
https://i.stack.imgur.com/chAwb.png

Comment: It looks like you posted 2 questions, though this one seems more complete so I'll mention it here.  It's possible that there is a software defect that makes the fan register as failed even though it's not.  I would say open a case with JTAC, but 15.1R7 is End of Support.  If you can post "show chassis hardware detail" I _might_ be able to get some more information.

Comment: here is the output : https://textuploader.com/1ehi9   but it seems the fan tray is working

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

If the fans are still turning but the sensor says they aren't, it's most likely a sensor malfunction.

Since your devices probably aren't covered by support, swap the fan tray into a different slot or chassis and see if the problem remains with that QFX3500's slot or if it remains with the tray.  This will tell you which piece of hardware to consider replacing.